# how to target a checkbox inside a div inside a div table

Tags: html, css

im trying to add the input/label inside a toggle/div to hide the list of input but cant seem to target it without the checkbox not working. i tried adding the div#cars:checked ~ .container .cars{} but still not working.all i want is to wrap the input in a table example

```
<div class="parkingDivTable" style="border:solid 2px black;">
<table>
<input type="checkbox"  id="all" checked> Show all<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cars"> Cars<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="animals"> Animals<br>
<input type="checkbox"  id="fruits"> Fruits<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="color" > Colors<br>
</table>
</div>
```

something like this but the input only works outside the div any suggestions

```css
#all:checked  ~ .container .filterDiv{
  display: block;
  border:red solid 2px;
}


.filterDiv, :not(#all):checked ~ .container  .filterDiv{
  float: left;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px;
  display: none;
  border:solid 2px blue;
}


#animals:checked ~ .container .animals,
#fruits:checked ~ .container .fruits,
#color:checked ~ .container .colors{
  display: block;
  
}

#cars:checked ~ .container .cars
{
  display: block;
  border:green solid 2px;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h2>Filter DIV Elements</h2>


<input type="checkbox"  id="all" checked> Show all<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="cars"> Cars<br>
<input type="checkbox"  id="animals"> Animals<br>
<input type="checkbox"  id="fruits"  > Fruits<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="color" > Colors<br>


<div class="container">
  <div class="filterDiv cars">BMW</div>
  <div class="filterDiv colors fruits">Orange</div>
  <div class="filterDiv cars">Volvo</div>
  <div class="filterDiv colors">Red</div>
  <div class="filterDiv cars animals">Mustang</div>
  <div class="filterDiv colors">Blue</div>
  <div class="filterDiv animals">Cat</div>
  <div class="filterDiv animals">Dog</div>
  <div class="filterDiv fruits">Melon</div>
  <div class="filterDiv fruits animals">Kiwi</div>
  <div class="filterDiv fruits">Banana</div>
  <div class="filterDiv fruits">Lemon</div>
  <div class="filterDiv animals">Cow</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I hate to tell you that this is most likely impossible due to the nature of css. You see, once your checkbox is wrapped inside a div it does not share the same parent with the filtered divs, which makes tilde selector (~) useless. You're either gonna have to use javascript or wait for the parent selectors to arrive.

Comment: when you mean wait for the "parent selectors to arrive you mean theirs never coming?

Comment: haha, sort of... I heard it was proposed and rejected already.

Comment: crap. im a noob and just figuring javascript out takes me time to digest it. i tried it and took too long to figure out so i went for css for the simplicit. i have a demo this guy gave me but modifying for myself is another story.

Comment: I understand. Well, using pure css is always the way to go - if possible. Would a JS snippet based on your posted sample help?

Comment: i tried this demo that was pre written in jquery but to bugged when trying to edit it to buttons and also when trying to surround it with div. but if u have any simple solution it would be great. im trying now to look at the javascript even though im not that good at understanding im so so. i understand like 50% of it. the rest of the time i spend wondering why they decided to write it that way and why it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155132/discussion-between-angel-ramirez-and-manuel-otto).

Comment: By the way, you can't put an <input> in a <table>. If using a table, put the <input> in a <td> inside.